# How to use Map.computeIfAbsent() in a stream?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

I have a fun puzzler. Say I have a list of `String` values:

```
["A", "B", "C"]
```

Then I have to query another system for a `Map<User, Long>` of *users* with an attribute that corresponds to those values in the *list* with a *count*:

```
{name="Annie", key="A"} -> 23
{name="Paul", key="C"} -> 16
```

I need to return a new `List<UserCount>` with a count of each *key*. So I expect:

```
 {key="A", count=23},
 {key="B", count=0},
 {key="C", count=16}
```

But I'm having a hard time computing when one of my `User` objects has no corresponding `count` in the *map*.

I know that `map.computeIfAbsent()` does what I need, but how can I apply it based on *what's on the contents of the original list*?

I think I need to stream the over the original list, then apply compute? So I have:

```
valuesList.stream()
 .map(it -> valuesMap.computeIfAbsent(it.getKey(), k-> OL))
 ...
```

But here's where I get stuck. Can anyone provide any insight as to how I accomplish what I need?

Comment: You mean something like this? `List<UserCount> list = valuesList.stream().map(it -> new UserCount(it.getKey(), valuesMap.computeIfAbsent(it.getKey(), k -> 0L))).collect(Collectors.toList())` (assuming `UserCount` has a constructor `UserCount(String key, long count)`

Comment: `valuesList` is the `List<String>` and `valuesMap` is the `Map<User, Long>` right? Then where does `it.getKey()` come from? `it` should be a `String` and does not have a `getKey` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an auxiliary `Map<String, Long>` which will associate each *string key* with the *count* and then generate a list of `UserCount` based on it.

*Example:*

```
public record User(String name, String key) {}
public record UserCount(String key, long count) {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> keys = List.of("A", "B", "C");
    
    Map<User, Long> countByUser =
        Map.of(new User("Annie", "A"), 23L,
               new User("Paul", "C"), 16L));
    
    Map<String, Long> countByKey = countByUser.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey().key(), 
            Collectors.summingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)));

    List<UserCount> userCounts = keys.stream()
        .map(key -> new UserCount(key, countByKey.getOrDefault(key, 0L)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(userCounts);
}
```

*Output*

```
[UserCount[key=A, count=23], UserCount[key=B, count=0], UserCount[key=C, count=16]]
```

Regarding the idea of utilizing `computeIfAbsent()` with stream - this approach is wrong and discouraged by the [documentation of the Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

Sure, you can use `computeIfAbsent()` to solve this problem, but not in conjunction with streams. It's not a good idea to create a stream that operates via side effects (*at least without compelling reason*).

And I guess you even don't need Java 8 `computeIfAbsent()`, plain and simple `putIfAbsent()` will be sufficient.

The following code will produce the same result:

```
Map<String, Long> countByKey = new HashMap<>();

countByUser.forEach((k, v) -> countByKey.merge(k.key(), v, Long::sum));
keys.forEach(k -> countByKey.putIfAbsent(k, 0L));

List<UserCount> userCounts = keys.stream()
            .map(key -> new UserCount(key, countByKey.getOrDefault(key, 0L)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And instead of applying `forEach()` on a *map* and *list*, you can create two enhanced `for` loops if this options looks convoluted.

Comment: Thanks so much! The “auxiliary HashMap” was the clue I needed!

Answer (score 0):

```java
final Map<User,Long> valuesMap = ...

// First, map keys to counts (assuming keys are unique for each user) 
final Map<String,Long> keyToCountMap = valuesMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().key, e -> e.getValue()));

final List<UserCount> list = valuesList.stream()
  .map(key -> new UserCount (key, keyToCountMap.getOrDefault(key, 0L)))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How does that count an element that's missing from the map?

Comment: You are right @CNDyson, i missed that point. I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Another educational and parallel friendly version would be to gather the logic in one place and build your own custom accumulator and combiner for the Collector

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<User, Long> countByUser =
            Map.of(new User("Alice", "A"), 23L,
                    new User("Bob", "C"), 16L);

    List<String> keys = List.of("A", "B", "C");

    UserCountAggregator userCountAggregator =
            countByUser.entrySet()
                    .parallelStream()
                    .collect(UserCountAggregator::new,
                            UserCountAggregator::accumulator,
                            UserCountAggregator::combiner);

    List<UserCount> userCounts = userCountAggregator.getUserCounts(keys);
    System.out.println(userCounts);
}
```

Output

```
[UserCount(key=A, count=23), UserCount(key=B, count=0), UserCount(key=C, count=16)]
```

User and UserCount classes with Lombok's @Value

```
@Value
class User {
    private String name;
    private String key;
}

@Value
class UserCount {
    private String key;
    private long count;
}
```

And the UserCountAggregator which contains your custom accumulator and combiner

```
class UserCountAggregator {
    private Map<String, Long> keyCounts = new HashMap<>();

    public void accumulator(Map.Entry<User, Long> userLongEntry) {
        keyCounts.put(userLongEntry.getKey().getKey(),
                keyCounts.getOrDefault(userLongEntry.getKey().getKey(), 0L) 
                        + userLongEntry.getValue());
    }

    public void combiner(UserCountAggregator other) {
        other.keyCounts
                .forEach((key, value) -> keyCounts.merge(key, value, Long::sum));
    }

    public List<UserCount> getUserCounts(List<String> keys) {
        return keys.stream()
                .map(key -> new UserCount(key, keyCounts.getOrDefault(key, 0L)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  I have been interested in understanding just how to provide and accummulator/combiner.  A nice simple example right here for me. :-)